# Defining a Constant for new SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, java-6, thread-local

I am building a java application. My application is not multithreading and i want to declare constant for the `SimpleDateFormat` so i can use it at multiple place.

1.

```
public static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

2. 

```
public static SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

In Normal java application which approach is better. As i know `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe and i am trying to mark it as static which is not good.
Which approach is better will be better in normal java application.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They are also thread safe, so solve your problem completely no m,atter if your program is multi-threaded or not.

Comment: Java 6? There are a million reasons why you should want to upgrade. Have you examined the security risks with such an old version? However the need to use java.time is not one of the reasons since java.time has been backported to Java 6 in [the ThreeTen Backport project](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). I’m not sure whether the newest version only works with Java 7, but if so, find an earlier one.

Comment: @Zia If you are till using java6 how could you use lambda expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate               // All java.time classes are threads-safe, unlike the troublesome legacy date-time classes. 
.parse( "2023-01-23" )  // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format by default, without defining any formatting pattern. 
.toString()             // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## 1. versus 2.

If you are *absolutely* sure this object will never ever be accessed across threads, then your two options serve equally well.

If there is *any* chance of future use of multiple threads, then you must use the first, with a `ThreadLocal`.

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is not thread-safe. This means using an object of that class to parse or generate text across threads may result in undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is bad.

So the second approach you showed creates one object to be used across threads. Not good. The first approach creates one object per thread, so it can only be used singularly, never used across threads. That is better.

There is no downside to making a `ThreadLocal`. So I would certainly recommend that for objects known to be *not* thread-safe whenever there is *any* chance of multithreaded use now or in the future.

## *java.time*

But the best approach is to **stop using `SimpleDateFormat`**. That class is part of the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, having been supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

One of the many advantages of *java.time* is thread-safety across all its classes.

So you can create a `DateTimeFormatter` (replacement for `SimpleDateFormat`) any where you want, and use it across threads if you want. No problem.

For extreme cases where you make heavy use of a `DateTimeFormatter`, you may want to create a singleton for  reuse rather than re-instantiating repeatedly.

Furthermore, your desired format is the default format used by `LocalDate#parse` and `LocalDate#toString`. So no need for any formatter object at all!

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2023-01-23" ) ;
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

If stuck on Java 6 or Java 7, add the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project. This library provides much of the *java.time* functionality with virtually identical API. But I *strongly* suggest you consider moving to a [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java: Java 8, 11, or 17.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single thread and don't see any reasonable chance you'll have to introduce another in the near future, there's no need to use a `ThreadLocal`. Having it as `public static final` should be fine.

Comment: Declaring it as static final will give Non-thread-safe fields should not be static

Comment: I would suggest the opposite. If there is *any* chance of multi-threaded usage, then use the ThreadLocal. No downside to making a ThreadLocal. Why take the chance on eventually encountering transient broken behavior bugs in future updates of this app?